# Array of arrays of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array that looks like this.

> ```
> let name 
> function arrayfunction () {
>         selling = confirmedSale
>         testSample = {something:das, something1: dso}
>         productName = [name, selling ,testSample]
>         qualifiedProduct = ["Selling", productName]
>         qualified.push(qualifiedProduct); 
> }
> ```

I want to be able to search by name and do work on that name. However, the challenge I am encountering is that it's a nested array of arrays with an object. I have figured out how to do work on the object via two foreach loops but am unable to delete productName and all related elements when the work is complete.
console logging qualified through each of my sets of creating the array to buying and selling is working great and works as it should. Now, I want to delete the productName and all associated elements to productName from the array of Buying and Selling once I have finished doing work on it.
I am relatively new to programming and any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: you might want to look at some javscript function like [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) & [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Comment: @ChrisG Best I can explain is this.. [Selling Array [ProductName, {testSample}] How do I do I find and delete ProductName?

Comment: @j4rey so your saying I should do a map on the array and filter it for what I want and then delete the index accordlingly?

Comment: I'm having trouble making sense of this structure. Generally, arrays should be used for homogeneous data, objects should be used for heterogeneous data. `[name, selling, testSample]` violates this principle.

Comment: @Barmar I disagree. Since JavaScript doesn't have tuples, arrays will be used as such. It's not uncommon to see tuples with non-homogeneous data.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I'm not a big fan of tuples, either. Numeric indexes are not as readable as named properties.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks I wrote that as an example. And thankfully you and Barmar noticed my error. And both of you obviously understood the question and had the answer. So the definition I need to learn is tuples.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Actually javascript doesn't care about a comma. It's on a different line and for whatever reason knows its a global var as that is what its purpose is.  Like I, said I'm learning so I don't have all the answers and will never argue from ignorance.

Comment: @3limin4t0r let name is, in fact, a global var... All the other jazz was in a function that maybe I should specify, but felt that giving you all that I gave you was enough. When I was in school I had the worst penmanship and its morphed to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `findIndex()` to find the index of the product with the name you want to remove.

```
index = qualified.findIndex(q => q[0] == "Selling" && q[1][0] == "someName");
if (index != -1) {
    qualified.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: it worked! Thank you! :)  And are you suggesting im going about it a very wrong way?

Comment: Can you break down what this means? q => q[0] == "Selling" && q[1][0] == "someName"

Comment: I'm just unwrapping the arrays that you constructed. `q` is the array `["Selling", productName]`, so `q[0]` is the keyword `"Selling"` for these records.

Comment: `q[1]` is `productName`, which is `[name, selling, testsample]`, so `q[1][0]` is `name`.

Comment: You could replace `q => q[0] == "Selling" && q[1][0] == "someName"` with `([status, [name]]) => status == "Selling" && name == "someName"` which is better understandable in my opinion, although it takes up a bit more characters.

Comment: @3limin4t0r True, although that presumes that the structure of the second element will be the same when the first element is something other that `"Selling"`

Comment: Since these arrays seem to be heterogeneous, I didn't want to make that assumption.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. The values are heterogeneous but must maintain a strict homogeneous structure that needs to be maintained. I feel like a new career for me is just learning how to manipulate arrays to do work on them! Again thank you.